# What is a command line alternative to top for finding current CPU utilization that isn't dependent on screen width?

Tags: linux, shell, process

If I run `top -p <myPID> -n 1` with a terminal that isn't wide enough, the CPU utilization % is omitted from the output.  When trying to find a process' cpu utilization via bash scripting, this is a huge problem, as the script won't work if the terminal you're running it in isn't wide enough.

`ps -oe pcpu,pid,cmd` will give me the total average cpu, but not a running utilization.

Is there a command that I can use to get the current cpu utilization of a process that isn't dependent on terminal width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [sysstat package](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) includes mpstat. Running

```
mpstat 2 | awk '{print $11}'
```

Gave me the idle-time percentage which seems like the inverse of what you want, so you might need to do a little work on mpstat output:

```
8 % mpstat 2 | awk '{print $11}'

%idle
100.00
99.50
100.00
100.00
100.00
100.00
```

I had mpstat on my Slackware 11 system, but it didn't appear on my Arch system until I did `pacman -S sysstat`

Answer (score 2):

In your script, set the COLUMNS environment variable to be sufficiently high to get the output you need.

```
export COLUMNS=100
top -p ...
```

You could also change the COLUMNS var just for the `top` invocation thusly:

```
COLUMNS=100 top -p ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `f` key to adjust the columns displayed. Remove some columns and add the CPU%. You should be able to see it then.

Comment: He's trying to do this from a script.  As far as I can tell, `top` doesn't have a command-line option to specify columns.

Comment: Well how about a Python script? Use the [CPUMeasurer](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/core/pycopia/OS/Linux/procfs.py#253) object from the procfs module.

Comment: Yea, you can't use the interactive features of `top` from a script, so this won't work.

Comment: My script doesn't use top, it computes CPU utilization directly the same way top does.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps u -p <PID>
```

Works fine.  you also might try using `awk` with it:

```
 pid=16707; ps u -p $pid --no-heading | awk -v pid=${pid} -F" " '{print "CPU usage for "$11": "$3}'
```

Comment: This doesn't work either.  I need the _current_ cpu utilization.  `ps` just gives the total average historical utilization.

Comment: Try this one:  

    `top -n 1 -p 13145 | grep PID --after 1 | grep -v PID | awk -F" " '{print $1}'`

Comment: I can't use top, because if the window running the shell is too narrow, top won't display the CPU info.